# how to fix one Git not detect newly added files

Tags: git, github, windows-10

I have two git clones from github

Ex-

```
C:\Git\gitA
C:\Git\gitB
```

I'm using git desktop on my windows 10, when i **edit** a file it detect on both gits by git desktop software and i can push those.

But problem is when i **add a new file** to above folders, my git desktop software only detect for **gitA**

**GitB** doesn't detect any newly added files so i have to add those directly using github.com.

It seems .gitignore file have some restriction when i remove both /* from it it shows newly added file, othe other folder file have only one /* I'm not sure what is that, here i paste the file contents

```
/*
!.gitignore
!app/
!app/*
!js/
!js/*
!skin/
!skin/*
!lib/
!lib/*
!downloader/
!downloader/*
!index.php
!ipcheck.inc.php
!.htaccess
# But not these files...
/*
!ajax/
!ajax/*
!ajax/error_log
!error/
!error/*
!get.php
!api.php
!autocomplete.php
!index.php
.DS_Store
._.DS_Store
**/.DS_Store
**/._.DS_Store
```

The other folder

```
# Ignore everything
/*
!.gitignore
!app/
!app/*
!js/
!js/*
!skin/
!skin/*
!lib/
!lib/*
!downloader/
!downloader/*
!ajax/
!ajax/*
!error/
!error/*
!get.php
!api.php
!index.php
!autocomplete.php
.DS_Store
._.DS_Store
**/.DS_Store
**/._.DS_Store

# But not these files...
```

Anyone know how to fix this problem? Do I need some changes on git desktop app, or git repository on github.com?

Comment: Run `git add myfile` in the repository where the file "myfile" is not tracked

Comment: @UnbearableLightness there have hundreds of files :)

Comment: Your question seems to amount to "how does `.gitignore` work". There are a lot of examples of how to use `.gitignore` directives already on StackOverflow....